# Do I have a serious memory leak problem?

Tags: c#, performance, forms, memory-leaks, memory-management

I'm building a windows form application in C# that reads from hundreds of file and create an object hierarchy. In particular:

```
DEBUG[14]: Imported 129 system/s, 6450 query/s, 6284293 document/s.
```

The sum is the total number of object I've created. Objects are really simple by the way, just some int/string properties and strongly typed lists inside.

***Question**: is normal that my application is consuming about 700MB of memory (in debug mode)? What can I do for how to reduce memory usage?*

**EDIT**: here is why i have 6284293 objects, if you're just curious. Imagine a search engine, called "system". A system have more queries inside it.

```
public class System
{
  public List<Query> Queries;
}
```

Each query object refers to a "topic"; that is the main argument (eg. search for "italy weekend"). It ha a list of retrieved document inside:

```
public class Query
{
  public Topic Topic; // Maintain only a reference to the topic
  public List<RetrievedDocument> RetrievedDocuments;
  public System System; // Maintain only a reference to the system
}
```

Each retrieved document has a score and a rank and has a reference to the topic document:

```
public class RetrievedDocument
{
  public string Id;
  public int Rank;
  public double Score;
  public Document Document;
}
```

Each topic has a collection of documents inside, that can be relevant or not relevant, and a reference to its parent topic:

```
public class Topic
{
  public int Id;
  public List<Document> Documents;
  public List<Document> RelevantDocuments
  {
    get {return Documents.Where(d => d.IsRelevant());}
  }
}

public class Document
{
  public string Id;
  public bool IsRelevant;
  public Topic Topic; // Maintain only a reference to the topic
}
```

There are 129 systems, 50 main topics (129*50 = 6450 query objects), each query has a different number of retrieved documents, 6284293 in total. I need this hierarchy for doing some calculations (average precision, topic ease, system mean average precision, relevancy). This is how TREC works...

Comment: That sounds fairly reasonable, size wise.

Comment: Does `6284293 documents` mean you have 6284293 objects?

Comment: @Gabe: yes, that number is the total lines of all files imported (~130 txt files), and for each line an object of type "Document" is created...

Comment: So about 7M objects, at about 100 bytes each, gives you about 700MB. What's your problem, then?

Comment: @Gabe: I'm asking this because I'm not a guru.

Comment: Assuming each object has 8 bytes overhead, it looks like a `Document` object is 20 bytes plus 4 bytes for each reference to it. Then each one has a string, which you can assume will be 8 bytes overhead plus 8 bytes of bookkeeping plus the data in the strings themselves. That gives you a minimum of 40 bytes per object plus the length of the strings. Do you know what the average length of your `Id` strings is? If it's approaching 50 then your memory usage is as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're reading 6284293 documents and are holding on to these in an object hierarchy, then obviously your application if going to use a fair amount of memory. It is hard to say if you're using more than could be expected given that we don't know the size of these objects.

Also, remember that the CLR allocates and frees memory on behalf of your application. So even though your application has released memory this may not be immediately reflected on the process' memory usage. If the application is not leaking this memory will be reclaimed at some point, but you shouldn't expect to see managed memory usage immediately reflected in process memory usage as the CLR may hold on to memory to reduce the number of allocations/frees.

Comment: Right, the memory usage won't actually drop until the GC runs, correct?  Which I've found in practice can take a fair amount of time if there's plenty of RAM available and your app is generating objects quickly (i.e. doesn't have a lot of idle time).  The theory being I suppose that so long as you have RAM available, you don't need to GC (though in reality I've had issues with memory fragmentation when the GC wasn't collecting/consolidating fast enough)

Comment: @James B: GC will reclaim managed memory. However, the CLR may hold on to the memory allocated for the process beyond that. The CLR allocates and frees memory with the OS in chunks as an optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Go get the [scitech profiler](http://memprofiler.com/) (with two week free trial) and find out.

Watch out for empty lists, they take 40 bytes each.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what's going on without knowing more about your code, but here's some ideas and suggestions:

- Make sure you close files after you finish reading from them
- Make sure you're not maintaining references to objects that are no
  longer being used
- Look at what data structures you're using. Sometimes, there's a more
  memory-efficient way to arrange your
  data
- Look at your data types, are you using Long or Double in places where
  Byte would suffice?
- Every program will use more memory in Debug mode than not-Debug mode,
  but the difference should be on the
  order of single or 10's of megabytes,
  not hundreds.  Can you use task
  manager to check how much memory
  you're using outside of Debug mode?

Comment: It seems that, for my problem, modelling using object is the best way. Anyway in release mode it's still consuming around 700MB while importing files.

Comment: Agree with all of those, however, if he's creating these objects fairly quickly, it may be that the GC can't keep up with freeing up and consolidating the memory, even if he is releasing and closing all of his resources.  I think the bottom line is, if you're reading hundreds of files with a complete object hierarchy for each, you're going to eat up a lot of memory.